# Prove the orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mu)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

In problem 33 page 17 -18 on the book "A Hilbert space Problem Book", written by Paul. R Halmos, the author claimed that $e_n(z) = z^n \quad \text{for} \quad |z|=1$ forms an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mu)$.

I tried to prove that by writting $Z$ in exponential form, but I do not get the desired result. More precisely,
$\langle z_n,z_m\rangle=
\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 \quad \text{for} \quad m = n\\
0 \quad \text{for} \quad m \neq n
.
\end{matrix}\right.
$

I did as the following:

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$ then $z^n=e^{in\theta}$, $z^m=e^{im\theta}$.

So, 
$\langle e_n,e_m\rangle= \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{in\theta}e^{-im\theta}d\theta=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(n-m)\theta}d\theta$.

For $n\neq m$, $\langle e_n,e_m\rangle= \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(n-m)}d\theta = 0$,

For $n=m$, $\langle e_n,e_m\rangle= \int_{0}^{2\pi}1d\theta = 2\pi$, but not $1$.
.

Could you please help me to find my mistake, please?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Can you compute exactly the integral $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(n-m)\theta}d\theta$? Why it is not be $0$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The result should be $0$, but for $n=m$, it is not $1$. So, I confuse a little bit.

Comment: Orthogonal and orthonormal are related but not equal concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, it is an orthonormal basis. I editted.

Comment: Check on the definition of $\mu$. It's probably normalized to be a probability measure on the circle.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail, please? I thought that the measure does not effect to the integral.